# How to define the type "any string enum" in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I had to change per request a lot of number based enum to string enums and now I need to make an `enum` converter for the already stored `enum` values in a storage API, so I had:

```
enum MyEnum {
  FirstValue,
  SecondValue
}
```

which now is

```
enum MyEnum {
  FirstValue = "FirstValue",
  SecondValue = "SecondValue"
}
```

and recover some object stored like

```
myObject = {
  myEnum = 0
}
```

I have to recover that and store it again as:

```
myObject = {
  myEnum = 'FirstValue'
}
```

As for now I already have the logic for it but I have problems with my function definition, I do not know how to define an *"any string enum"* without adding a index signature to all my enums.

I tried to use an interface with an index signature

```
interface EnumToFix {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

but if I give it to my function I get as error:

> Argument of type 'typeof MyEnum' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EnumToFix'.
>         Index signature is missing in type 'typeof MyEnum'.

my current function definition is

```
private async fixGeneral<T>(storageKey: StorageKeyItems, enumToFix: EnumToFix, objectKeyToFix: keyof T): Promise<void>
```

If I ignore the error with `@ts-ignore` it works as expected.

Comment: You can use a generic constraint to restrict a type to only those whose known properties are all `string`-valued, which may be enough for you, like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgJwJYgOYFFzQN4FgBQUUAYkggM5wBqAhgDZjBQC8UARKRdfY2wDQEiMYAGMA9iAAmtBk1Zth4qTN4EAvgQKhIUAHKRgyEZh15CREmUorgA80NETpPYOs34AZmBAi4SCVA0IiLAAA5w8MhoJhAAPAAqUMAAHnCgkuRQAEqOCJKxANbAAJ5iHlDxfFCUUagAfHUAFDUoGFgAXBUAlJ0AbmJIklBmbvgEQSHhka0xjdPRWF0A3FAA9KtQYgU0xePBYRGIM1iN+hCGSMaLK+tJCAhiCHoGRjEAdJzWLlBImSBicEC1UQaD2k0OtVm2GqYnOcAAFq1Omx4SU2FA1Ms1ht6OQxJttsUgA). If that helps I can make an answer.

Comment: Your link looks like what I need. I could not make it work for my use case though. I you can could you please make an answer? :)

Comment: I used the same enum in my link as in your example code; what doesn’t work in your use case?  Can you make sure the question has a [mcve] so I’m sure my answer will work?  It should be example code that can be dropped into a standalone IDE and demonstrate the issue (and *only* that issue).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I can not reproduce it in the typescript playground. Also I do not get any error in VScode but I get one in the Angular Compiler (my project is an Ionic/Angular project). So I will assume this is an error within angular.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is okay, to just cast an object to unknown and then in your target type, when you KNOW it better. But you would need to provide the logic inside your "fixGeneral" function, to convert myObject properly. So you could do something like this:

```
enum MyEnum {
    FirstValue = "FirstValue",
    SecondValue = "SecondValue"
  }

let myObject: { myEnum: string | number } = { myEnum: 0 };

for (const propName of Object.keys(myObject)) 
    if (typeof myObject[propName] === "number") 
        myObject[propName] = MyEnum[myObject[propName]];

let myObjectTyped = myObject as unknown as { myEnum: MyEnum };
```

When you meant something different, I would ask you for more details/code. :)